# WSO2 ESB 4.9 Call mediator is not working fine in same situations

Tags: wso2-esb

I have a proxy service with below definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
   name="TestProxy"
   transports="https,http"
   statistics="disable"
   trace="disable"
   startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <header name="Action" value="urn:loadPerson"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <sear:loadPerson xmlns:sear="http://localhost/SearchService">
                  <sear:Id>1234</sear:Id>
               </sear:loadPerson>
            </format>
        <args/>
     </payloadFactory>
     <log level="full"/>
     <call>
        <endpoint key="SearchService"/>
     </call>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

So it's work fine when I call the proxy service(by tryIt) first time and I get right response of proxy service but for the next time it faces a problem and show me fault response:

```
<soapenv:Fault xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <faultcode>axis2ns11:Server</faultcode>
   <faultstring>Missing operation for soapAction [urn:loadPerson] and body element [null] with SOAP Version [SOAP 1.1]</faultstring>       
   </soapenv:Fault>
```

As you can see I log the message and it's the same for every proxy call:

```
INFO - LogMediator To: /services/TestProxy.TestProxyHttpSoap11Endpoint, WSAction: urn:loadPerson, SOAPAction: urn:loadPerson, MessageID: urn:uuid:cc9557cc-e2a0-4b8d-97a8-ae393a411157, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><sear:loadPerson xmlns:sear="http://localhost/SearchService"><sear:Id>1234</sear:Id></sear:loadPerson></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I found that the problem resolved by restarting the server(not redeploying the proxy service) or leave it for few minutes!
any idea?!

Comment: If you are still getting this problem, you can try logging more properties from the request - in the detail section, you can use the expression option and `get-property('OperationName')` - just a tiny idea.

Comment: OperationName is mediate,

Comment: the problem is when I use Mock services that generated by SoapUI! I check some other sample web services but everything is fine but when I call a mock service generated by SoupUI(ver 5.1.2) I face the problem! so strange!

Comment: Since OperationName is mediate, that means it doesn't recognize the operation. Perhaps the request itself is not accurate? Or the schema/wsdl? Another idea - shouldn't the prefix be the same in the header action value and in the request? Not completely sure of this, though - haven't really tried it myself.

Comment: What's about SoapUI mock services, have you ever tried them with call mediator?

Comment: Yes,  I have. Just not with that header. I could test this on Monday and see if I could figure out something. Unless you or someone else solves it in the meantime.

Comment: I don't really see a reason why this shouldn't work - I have tried it - literally the same thing, and there were no issues. Make sure that loadPerson is properly defined in your wsdl and in the service itself.  I have no other ideas at the moment.

Comment: Thanks @MariaDeleva for you replies. as I said the Action is defined in header and it's in wsdl too and everything is fine for first call but in other next call the problem is occurred. anyway I don't have any problem with endpoints on wso2 ESB or wso2 DSS but with SoapUI mock services I got problem!! I don't know why! I have never had this problem with SoapUI mock services too!